# Does Caltrops affect flying opponents?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

While fighting through a tomb I encountered several flying opponents.  They were fairly quick and required some running away to deal with them effectively as a Demon Hunter.

They seemed to ignore Caltrops altogether.  Is this perception correct, do flying creatures actually fly and avoid the caltrops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Caltrops do affects flying opponents.  See 9:37 or 9:33 in this video where a bat triggers one.

Comment: A surprising result that a floor trap affects a flyer!!

Comment: It's clearer at 9:37 where you can see the snared message.

Comment: Yeah, not every ability is very "realistic" in that sense.  I suspect it would create unintended balance issues, and Blizzard seems to be aiming for a lot more equality between all classes.

Comment: If you note, you cannot walk under flying enemies. The game is actually very two-dimensional in this manner.

Comment: It works by magic :-)